# multiple divs same name change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I need to do is add a div in each of these divs but only one:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

and what I want it to change to is

```
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
```

What makes this difficult for me is that the `PHP` generating the code for each box is a function that uses `foreach`.

My Javascript at the moment that is not working is:

```
var k = 1;
$('div.box').each( function() { 
    $('.box').addClass('box' + k);
    k = k + 1; 
});
```

Comment: Why does the input have 4 DIVs, but the result only has 3? Which one should be removed?

Comment: Already two correct answers below, please choose one as the right answer to help others looking for solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing all of the elements, you want to only reference the current one. jQuery makes that easy since `this` is the element.

Change

```
$('.box').addClass('box' + k);
```

to

```
$(this).addClass('box' + k);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Sadly the same issue.

Comment: The result is <div class="box box1 box2"></div> <div class="box box1 box2"></div> <div class="box"></div>

Comment: Maybe its simply that the javascript is processing when the PHP is still generating the boxes. If I put the script at the bottom of the script might resolve it so its the last thing being processed. I will try this now and update.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.box').each(function(index, el){
   $(el).addClass('box' + (++index));
});
```